# PHP unique_array gets the wrong results

Tags: php, arrays, unique

i'm trying to keep only unique IDs in my array but i'm having trouble with it..

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31
        )

)
```

that's my array and when i use-

```
$unique = array_unique($myArray);
```

i get only-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )
)
```

i need it to show both ids 1 and 31

what am i doing wrong please?

the code-

```
$myArray= array();

$myArray= $this->data['vendor_id'];

$unique = array_unique($myArray);

print_r($unique);
```

Comment: If you checked the documentation that explains how `array_unique` works you would know why it happens for sure. But instead of that you for some reason are making (wrong) guesses about how it could work. Just in case you don't know where php documentation is hosted: http://php.net/array_unique

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

```
<?php
$data = array(
    1 => array(
        0 => 1
    ),
    2 => array(
        0 => 1
    ),
    3 => array(
        0 => 1
    ),
    4 => array(
        0 => 31
    )
);

$items = array();

foreach($data as $item) {
    $items[$item[0]] = $item[0];
}

print_r($items);
```

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but I can say that your answer neither explains the issue, nor adds any value. This might be a solution to refactoring an array, but it is clearly not what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the value of each of the array items is an array. The `array_unique()` function essentially removes the duplicates and keeps only the first occurrence of the array.

See this page for further reading: [PHP documentation: array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)